# Delete a worksheet and recreate with the same sheet name

Tags: vba, excel, addition, worksheet

I'm currently trying to delete a worksheet and auto create a new worksheet with the same name.

I'm using the below code. However, when i run the code the windows pop up appears asking me to confirm deletion, i want to prevent this and just delete and replace with a new sheet. I want to avoid Send-keys for this.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Process Map").delete
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Process Map"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the DisplayAlerts to False (then back to true if that is what you want as the default setting.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next 
ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Process Map").Delete 
On Error Goto 0 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Process Map"
```

Or without error handling:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Process Map").Delete 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Process Map"
```

Comment: No worries, if it worked could you accept the answer so others know that it worked for your situation (and helps me a bit as well).
Thanks and all the best.

Comment: @tyblu In case the line of code does not work it continues anyway